# Unrecognizable database format

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, adodb

I am trying to connect to a remote Access 2010 database from a client system.

My connection string is as follows:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\<ipaddress>\<sharedfolder>\<databasename>.accdb"
```

I get run time error

> Run-time error 2147467259  Unrecognizable database format

How can i fix this ?
Or is there an alternate way of connecting to a remote database?

I am currently trying ODBC but I do not see the Access drivers for some reason despite installing data access components. FYI the database is Access 2010 database. I am trying to connect from Excel 2007 vba code. I can access the shared folder with no issues.

Comment: Is \\<ipaddress>\<sharedfolder>\ a mapped path to your machine? Do  note: you cannot run Access remotely.

Comment: Yes it is. The folder is shared and mapped.

Comment: If mapped, what letter drive? Try using the local, mapped address. Curious if you type that address in Windows Explorer path bar and press enter does the database open?

Comment: Thank you. I tried it again and it is working now.